# Using Rule of Inference, How to derive following conclusion from given premises?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Question is from the book: *Discrete Mathematical Structures with Applications to CS by Tremblay and Manohar*. It is an exercise problem. But, unfortunately, there is no help available on answers, or solutions of this book. I have tried to solve this problem but couldn't get the desired conclusion.

Premise 1: $P \rightarrow Q$,

Premise 2: $(\neg Q \lor R) \wedge \neg R$

Premise 3: $ \neg (\neg P \wedge S)$

Conclusion: $ \neg S$

Solution:

1. $(\neg Q \lor R)$ $\wedge$ $-R$..............[Introducing **Premise** **2**]
2. $(\neg Q \lor R)$.........................[Tautologically Implies, **1**, Simplification]
3. $Q \rightarrow R$.............................[Tautologically Implies, **2**, Converting Disjuction To Implication]
4. $P \rightarrow Q$.............................[Introducing **Premise** **1**]
5. $P \rightarrow R$.............................[Tautologically Implies, **4**, **3**, Transitivity Law]
6. $ \neg (\neg P \wedge S)$.......................[Introducing **Premise** **3**]
7. $P \lor \neg S$............................[Tautologically Implies, **6**, DeMorgan's Law]
8. $ \neg S \lor P$............................[Tautologically Implies, **7**, Commutative Law]
9. $S \rightarrow P$............................[Tautologically Implies, **8**, Converting Disjuction to Implication]
10. $S \rightarrow R$............................[Tautologically Implies, **9**, **5**, Transitivity]
11. $\neg S \lor R$............................[Tautologically Implies, **10**, Converting Implication to Disjuction]

What wrong I did?
I am getting $\neg S \lor R$ instead of $\neg S $

Comment: You didn't take much benefit from premisse $2$. That's why you didn't get the desired conclusion. But your reasonning is Correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

From premisse $ 2$, use distributivity to get $ \lnot Q \wedge \lnot R$ because $ R\wedge \lnot R $ is false.

by simplification, you have $ \lnot Q$.

by contrapositive of premmisse $ 1$, you get $ \lnot P.$

Finally,  using  premisse $ 3$, De Morgan's law and disjunctive syllogism, you have the conclusion $\lnot S$.

Comment: There it is... I really missed that one out.

Comment: How do we get $\neg Q$ from $\neg Q\land\neg R$?

Comment: @Croissant by simplification .